How to use the web developer console when sites detect its use?
There are JavaScript libraries (such as dev-tools-monitor, devtools-detector, devtools-detect and others) that detect when the developer console is open. Are there also ways to better hide the dev-tools such that they are no longer detectable?
I had a problem with one of these libraries when I wanted to inspect a suspicious popup and it closed itself every time I opened the developer console. While it might be possible to insert JavaScript code as userscript, I don't know a way to monitor network requests in the browser without opening the developer tools. And in the end, one shouldn't have to use many workarounds, but rather have an undetectable tool to look at browser internals without sites detecting it.
I tried having a detached console open before loading the page and when the page still detected the console I tried changing the URL with JavaScript from a blank page to the target page and it was still detected. On one try I got a (wrong) redirect instead of a closed window with one of the library names of a library that combines several detected techniques showing that the page is actively avoiding debugging tools.

This question is off-topic on Security SE. I suggest to move it to SO. Independent on this: 1) Often such tools use onDevToolsOpen event. If you open developer console before you load the page, the page will not get this event. 2) Try any IDE like IntelliJ IDEA or VS Code. They support remote debugging in browser. Then you will not need developer console at all.

In that case I tried changing the URL with detached devtools open and even tried changing the URL using JavaScript instead of the address bar, and each time it was detected. Some of the detection libraries combine multiple techniques, like monitoring window size, watching for the devtool hotkeys, checking for variables only present when devtools are open, testing for altered behavior in the page, and more. As some of these libraries behave more like malware trying to evade detection than like helpful tools, I posted to the security StackExchange instead of StackOverflow.

Why you want to open the dev console isn't inherently a security concern, and the reasons why doesn't affect the answer. So, the fact that you want to do this for analysing malware isn't relevant.

there are various debuggers you can run inside or outside the browser... fiddler, greasemonkey, wireshark, etc...  why people are trying to obfuscate non-obsfuscatable code is beyond me, though.  Reminds of those sites in the old days that would alert you if you right-clicked on the page...
